# File search taking too much time

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

i am trying to search for plist here named 1 to 6 and ive written this code and its making the app consume 3 more seconds to load then original time ....the code is

```
for (int i=1;i<6;i++) {
    NSString *bundleRoot = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
    NSArray *dirContents = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] directoryContentsAtPath:bundleRoot];
    for (NSString *tString in dirContents) {
        if ([tString hasPrefix:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",i]] && [tString hasSuffix:@".plist"]) { 
            NSLog(@"file found");
            NSString *plist = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",i] ofType:@"plist"];
            mute = [NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:plist];
            [mute addObjectsFromArray:contentArray];
            contentArray = mute;
        }
        else {
            NSLog(@"not found");
        }
    }
}
```

can someone hit me with a solution or define what is wrong here

Comment: The loop won't run 6 times it will run only 5 times :)

Comment: +1 @LegendReborn :) (though you might just have made his code 20% slower ha ha)!

Comment: and i only want it to run 5 times ... wrote 6 by mistake ....

Answer (score 1):

That's not very efficient :)

Try this :

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 6; ++i) {
  // Load the plist
  NSString *plist = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",i] ofType:@"plist"];
  if (nil == plist) {
    NSLog(@"not found (%i)", i);
    continue;
  }

  // Do something with your plist
  mute = [NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:plist];
  [contentArray addObjectsFromArray:mute];
}
```

If you still get the 3 seconds delay then it's not the searching thats the problem, it's the size of the plists and the processing that you need to do to them. You might just have to put a 'please wait' message and a spinner when you load them.

Or you could try loading them on a background thread so your ui still works. I guess it depends on what else is happening in your app!

Comment: but its still taking too much time to load , plist has 50 entries could that be the problem .. each entry is of a joke comprising on 100 words

Comment: Hmm, if you made your contentArray NSMutableArray you could get each plist in there _slightly_ faster (see my edit). Though I doubt that will make much of a difference. How long is it taking?

Comment: wow, that's a very long time! Have you thought about using a database instead?

Comment: thanks to you the load time is now 4 seconds it was 7 seconds before when i was using my old code and now its 4 seconds

Comment: Sounds like the _3 more seconds_ you mentioned in your original question has gone away. I suspect that the delay is caused somewhere else in your app because there's no way that this should be taking 4 seconds! Have you tried running Instruments and seeing what's taking up the time? And 4 seconds to start isn't _that_ bad - you could probably get away with releasing that and improving it in a later release.

Comment: yes .. thanks a lot i owe you mann  . and i dont get the line where u said tries running instrument